# Column <<column_name>> not found when using ADO-NET connection for Postgresql in insert query

Tags: postgresql, ssis, ado.net

I have problem when using ADO.NET connection for PostgreSQL. I have tried this query using PSQLODBC driver 12.000.000 both ANSI and Unicode. I use PostgreSQL v.9.5. I notice the column name has "_" in its name.

When I use the Select query, the connection successfully execute it. The query return variables as I want.

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = (OdbcConnection)Dts.Connections["XXX"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction))
{
    try
    {
         if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
         {
             conn.Open();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String err = e.Message.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(err);
    }

    try
    {
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT XX FROM <<table>> where <<params>>";

        ...
        OdbcDataReader rdd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdd.Read())
        {
            <<read operation here>>;
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ers)
    {
        <<catch operation here>>;
    }
}
```

But when I use Insert query, it failed to check the column name, even the column are exist in my PostgreSQL tables:

```
 using (OdbcConnection conn2 = (OdbcConnection)Dts.Connections["OJK_REPORTING_DEV"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (conn2.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            conn2.Open();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        string x = e.Message.ToString();
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
                        cmd.Connection = conn2;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO <<table>>(<<column>>)VALUES(<<params>>)";
                        <<cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue here>>;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn2.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        <<exception catch here>>;
                    }
                }
```

When I debug this line, I get this error:

> ERROR[42703] ERROR: column <> not found, error while executing the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, after several research, I've got an answer. Since i use PostgreSQL ODBC, the query parameters are not using `@<name>` inside the query, but using `?`, so you need to formulate the query like

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> (<COLUMNS>) VALUE ?
```

and call the parameters

```
cmd.AddWithValue("@<name>",<value>)
```